# Generate background colour in listView from database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a listView generated from a database, is there a way to make a background colour or a picture to each "section" in the list:
if the first symbol in "Tip" is "W" the background should be Green, and if its "L" it should be red

Im thinking something like this, but i have no idea where to put it since it have to be done in every section:

```
tipvalue = BetsDbAdapter.KEY_TIP;
    //Here to split the value to gain only "W" or "L"
String arrtip[] = tipvalue.split(" ", 2);
temptip = arrtip[0];
    //then set background
if (temptip.equals("W")) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

To the left is my listView and right is the xml file to make each "section" in the listview

[image: Listview]  [image: storedbets.xml]

Here is my database:
[image]

This is code generating the listView

```
public class StoredBets extends Activity {

    private BetsDbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.results);
        dbHelper = new BetsDbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();    
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        displayListView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.results, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void testknap1(View v) {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(StoredBets.this, Overview.class);        
           startActivity(myIntent);     
    }

    private void displayListView() {
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllStats();

    String[] columns = new String[] {
            BetsDbAdapter.KEY_SMATCH,
            BetsDbAdapter.KEY_TIP,
            BetsDbAdapter.KEY_BETAMOUNT,
            BetsDbAdapter.KEY_BODDS
          };


      // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
      int[] to = new int[] { 
        R.id.smatch,
        R.id.tip,
        R.id.bodds,
        R.id.betamount,
      };

      // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
      //as well as the layout information
      dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.storedbets, 
        cursor, 
        columns, 
        to,
        0);

      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
      // Assign adapter to ListView
      listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
             int position, long id) {
           // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
           Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

           // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
           String betMatch = 
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("smatch"));
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             betMatch, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           Intent myIntent = new Intent(StoredBets.this, SetWinVoidLoss.class);
           myIntent.putExtra("id", id);
           startActivity(myIntent);      
           }
          });
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

@amal

This is the layout(results.xml) with the listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StoredBets" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"

        android:onClick="testknap1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your adapter class..thats where the condition should be applied..

Comment: Not this.. i want to see your "dataAdapter" which populates the xml resource in the listview

Comment: @Yoshidk first used custom adapter for your listview

Comment: ok, if i understand you correctly, i have added the layout.xml with the listView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get a fair idea from my code,
code snippet for displaying ListViews where the "curSelected" item has a different background:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter()
{
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = new TextView(ListHighlightTestActivity.this);
        convertView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        ((TextView)convertView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    convertView.setBackgroundColor((position == curSelected) ? 
        Color.argb(0x80, 0x20, 0xa0, 0x40) : Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    ((TextView)convertView).setText((String)getItem(position));

    return convertView;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return "item " + position;
}

public int getCount()
{
    return 20;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#tutorial_ownadapter) is a tutorial of how to write an adapter for a list view. amal is right, you can change the separate items in the list view in the `getView()` method.